# stretch draw text with Python Wand

Tags: python, wand

I am exploring how to get some image manipulation done with Python Wand.

I would like to know how to do a "stretch draw": fit a text with the boundaries of a certain box. In Delphi, this would be done drawing on a canvas, then do a copy onto another canvas.

The process in Python Wand is probably similar, but I have not been able to find the solution yet.
Given that I have the following script to create a bunch of identical images with a number:

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color

imagewidth=1800
imageheight=600

def makeImage(mynr):
    myimage = Image(
        width=imagewidth,
        height=imageheight,
        background=Color("white")
    )
    with Drawing() as draw:
        draw.font="Arial"
        draw.font_size=500
        draw.gravity="center"
        draw.text(0,0,f"{mynr:04d}")
        draw(myimage)

    # -- need to have 1 bit BMP images
    myimage.depth = 2
    myimage.type="bilevel"

    myimage.save(filename=f'test{mynr:02d}.bmp', )
    myimage = None
    print( mynr )  # to see progress

def do_numbers():
    for i in range(30):
        makeImage(i+1)

# ===============
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_numbers()
```

I get the following which is drawn OK in the right image format:

[image: Text as drawn by current script]

My goal is to have something like this, keeping image size. Text is stretched to fit image.

[image: Text as desired, stretched to fit]

(Note: images are scaled to 1/10 for clarity here, so won't match script output)

Comment: Add a `trim` after drawing it, then forcibly resize the trimmed text to what you want. On the command-line that would be `magick -background white -fill black -gravity center -size 1800x600 label:'0025' -trim -resize 1800x600\! text.png`

Comment: You really want to use `caption` to  draw text to fit a bounding box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this maybe closer to what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.font import Font

w, h = 1800, 600

# Create a white canvas
with Image(width=w, height=h, pseudo='xc:white') as canvas:
    with Drawing() as context:
        font = Font('/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Verdana.ttf', 0, "lime")
        context(canvas)
        canvas.caption('0025', width=w, height=h, font=font)
    canvas.trim()
    canvas.resize(w,h)
    canvas.save(filename='result.png')
```

[image]

---

Note that I had to do the following on macOS to help `wand` find my **ImageMagick** installation from **homebrew**:

```
# Help wand find ImageMagick
export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/homebrew
```

Comment: It certainly is closer. But how do I control the font in a pseudo / label situation ? I guess the number is already drawn at creation time.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised the font was important to you. I have added that aspect in, but used an Apple-supplied font - just replace it with your own.